# Debugging external libraries in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

In Java when I setup a library in Eclipse, I can point it to a source directory (assuming I have one), and when I am debugging I can actually step into the libraries source code.

I have found this very helpful at times.

Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio for C#?

Answer (score 1):

Disable `Just My Code`.

> To enable or disable Just My Code, choose Options and Settings on the Debug menu. In the Debugging / General node, choose or clear Enable Just My Code.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx

Comment: I tried that one, but when I do Step Into, it just does a Step Over. I don't think it has access to the source of the library. The specific library I am working with is MongoDb C# Driver which is installed through nuget.

Comment: it won't decompile it for you - you could always download the source and build it yourself.

Comment: *sigh* I am not looking for it to decompile it for me. This is why I was comparing it to the Eclipse feature, as I was hoping someone familiar with both toolsets can answer. All I really want to do is to download the source code, and just point the library reference to that source code so when I try to step into the function it will step through the source of the library function.

Answer (score 1):

In a VS environment, you generally need pdb files to enable debugging. If you have access to the pdb files you can point VS to them. See this article on how to specify Symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio Debugger http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx